# Complex integration with residues $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi}{(p+q\cos\phi)^2}=\frac{2\pi p}{(p^2-q^2)^{3/2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to show that $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi}{(p+q\cos\phi)^2}=\frac{2\pi p}{(p^2-q^2)^{3/2}}$ with $p>q>0$.

I set $C:z=e^{i\phi}\rightarrow dz=ie^{i\phi}=izd\phi$. Then I have that $\cos(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$.

Then I have $\oint_C=\frac{dz}{iz(p+q[\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})]^2}=\oint_C=\frac{dz}{iz(p+q(\frac{z}{2}+\frac{1}{2z}))^2}$
I know that I need to find what roots in denominator are equal to 0 in the denominator are in C in order to use residues. I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this. I know I can move the i to be -i in the numerator. Then I have $\oint_C=\frac{-idz}{z(p+q[\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})]^2}$. Then I have z=0 and two other roots, that I can't figure out... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(p%2Bq(z%2F2%2B2%2Fz))%5E2%3D0

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You do not really need the residue theorem or differentiation under the integral sign, it is enough to notice that under suitable constraints for $p,q$ the LHS is a multiple of the area enclosed by an ellipse. See page 47 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I appreciate that. I do want to try and use the residue theorem though. I am practicing for a test and this was a problem I couldn't figure out... Thanks.

Comment: In such a case, exploit symmetry to reduce the original integral to an integral over $(0,\pi/2)$, then substitute $\theta=\arctan z$ to end up with the integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$ of a rational function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Residues method:

After the usual sine/cosine substation you will get the integral

$$\int \frac{4z\ dz}{i(2pz + qz^2 + q)^2}$$

Thence your poles are at

$$z_{1, 2} = \frac{-p \pm \sqrt{p^2 - q^2}}{q}$$

By residues methods, you can easily obtain the wanted solution:

$$\boxed{\frac{2 \pi }{\sqrt{\frac{p-q}{p+q}} (p+q)}}$$

Comment: Hi thank you for the help. I am having a hard time seeing how you get the 4 in the numerator... Did I make a mistake or do I just need algebra from where I am at? Thanks

Comment: @MathIsHard When you are dealing with the denominator, you write:

$$\left(p + \frac{q}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)\right)^2$$

Unify the fractions:

$$\left(\frac{2pz + qz^2 + q}{2z}\right)^2$$

And here it is. The denominator, once squared and taken out, becomes $1/4z^2$. One $z$ get simplified and the $4$ jumps upside.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to instead compute (without loss of generality, taking $q=1$, if not normalizing)

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi}{p+\cos\phi}$$

by the same method as in Von Neumann's answer, and then differentiate the answer with respect to $p$. This is a bit less bothersome than the original problem.